# How to navigate to Begining/End of a curly brace by selecting one of the braces in Visual Studio 2005.?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2005, Consider my program has a loop containing 10000 lines of code with in it. If i select the Beginning or End brace '{ or }' of the loop, how can i navigate to the other brace'} or {' of the loop.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing ctrl + ] should take you to the matching close brace for any highlighted open brace (and indeed the matching start brace for any close brace selected)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, and pressing CTRL+] on the closing brace will take you to the opening brace. So it works both ways.